# ¿Cómo pasar la fecha de un JTable aaaa-mm-dd cuando lo seleccione a un JDateChooser

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Cuando selecciono una fila de un `JTable` quiero que aparezca la fecha de esa fila  en un `JDateChooser`

Comment: no resutla el codigo al final cuando lo asignas es fechaseleccionada o fecha solamente

Comment: amigo podrias ayudarme tengo el mismo problema y no puedo resolverlos

Answer (score 1):

Primero tienes que recuperar la fecha de la `JTable`, usaremos [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10703323/3850595):

```
int filaSeleccionada = jTable.getSelectedRow();
int columnaSeleccionada = jTable.getSelectedColumn();

String fechaSeleccionada = (String) jTable.getModel().getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, columnaSeleccionada);
```

Ahora, tenemos en la variable `fechaSeleccionada` una fecha del tipo `yyyy/MM/dd`, para asignarselo al `jDateChooser` vamos a necesitar usar el metodo [`JDateChooser::setDate(Date)`](http://www.se.rit.edu/~sal/uitutorials/uitot/api/com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser.html#setDate(java.util.Date)), para ello convertimos el string en fecha:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date fecha = df.parse(fechaSeleccionada);
```

Ahora ya solo nos falta asignarlo:

```
tuJDateChooser.setDate(fechaSeleccionada);
```

---

Listos, si tienes dudas, [sílbame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO7KYyDSkXA) `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono este código:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdformato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String fecha = (String) TujTable.getValueAt(filatabla, columnatabla);
jDateChooser.setDate(sdformato.parse(fecha);
```

Answer (score 0):

"dd/MM/yyyy" es el formato que tu estás capturando del jTable. Asi que si en tu jTable tiene otro formato como este "dd-MM-yyyy" u otro, tienes que ponerlo como tal!

Answer (score 0):

Java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "2017-10-14".

private void tablaproductosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatodeltexto = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy/MM/dd");
   String fecha =       
 tablaproductos.getValueAt(tablaproductos.getSelectedRow(),5).toString().trim();
 Date dato = null;
 try {
  dato = (Date) formatodeltexto.parse(fecha);  
  int row = tablaproductos.getSelectedRow();
  txfIdProducto.setText(tablaproductos.getModel().getValueAt(row, 
  0).toString());
  txfRef.setText(tablaproductos.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
  txfNombreProducto.setText(tablaproductos.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
  jSpinner1.setValue(tablaproductos.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3));
  txfPrecio.setText(tablaproductos.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());
   jDateChooser1.setDate(dato);
   } 

   catch (Exception e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

deber modificar en las propiedades del jdatechooser al siguiente formato
yyyy-MM-d